# Solve two parameters inside some integrals

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I have these equations,

$$\int_\epsilon^{z_m} \frac{z_m^d dz}{z^d \sqrt{f(z) z_m^{2d} - f(z_m) z^{2d}}} - \int_\epsilon^{z_s} \frac{z_s^d dz}{z^d \sqrt{f(z) (z_s^{2d} - z^{2d})}} = 0 \tag{1}\label{1}$$

$$T = \int_0^{z_s} \frac{z^d dz}{\sqrt{f(z) (z_s^{2d} - z^{2d})}} + b \tag{2}\label{2}$$

$$T = \int_0^{z_m} \frac{-dz}{f(z) \sqrt{1 - \frac{f(z) z_m^{2d}}{f(z_m) z^{2d}}}} - t_b \tag{3}\label{3}$$

where $b$, $t_b$ are constants, $\epsilon$ can be set to any small number, $z_h < z_m < z_{m-critical}$, $z_s < z_h$.

My goal is to find $z_m$ that satisfies equation $\eqref{1}$ ($z_m$ that makes the first equation to be 0). However, I also have this $z_s$ parameter which depends on $z_m$ through $T$ (before, I was solving for $z_s$ by giving a value to $T$ but now $T$ depends on the value of $z_m$ which is what I'm trying to find in the first place). So immediately, I think I can combine equation $\eqref{2}$ $\eqref{3}$ and together with equation $\eqref{1}$ I have two equations in two unknowns.

All of these integrals can be evaluated except for the integral in $\eqref{3}$ which diverges at $z=z_h$ ($z_h$ is just a number which I show in the code). However, using the `Method -> PrincipalValue` in `NIntegrate` this problem can be resolved.

```
d = 3;
b = 0.1;
tb = 10.103;
zmcritical = 13.128;
zh = 10;
f[z_] := 1 - (z/zh)^(d + 1)
Sv[z_?NumericQ, zm_?NumericQ] := zm^d/(z^d Sqrt[zm^(2 d) f[z] - z^(2 d) f[zm]])
SA[z_?NumericQ, zs_?NumericQ] := zs^d/(z^d Sqrt[f[z] (zs^(2 d) - z^(2 d) )])
SvA[zm_?NumericQ, zs_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Sv[z, zm], {z, 10^-1, zm}] - NIntegrate[SA[z, zs], {z, 10^-1, zs}]
tzm[z_?NumericQ, zm_?NumericQ] := -1/(f[z] Sqrt[1 - (zm^(2 d) f[z])/(z^(2 d) f[zm])])
tzs[z_?NumericQ, zs_?NumericQ] := z^d/Sqrt[f[z] (zs^(2 d) - z^(2 d) )]
tzmzs[zm_?NumericQ, zs_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[tzm[z, zm], {z, 0, zh, zm}, Method -> PrincipalValue] - NIntegrate[tzs[z, zs], {z, 0, zs}] - b - tb

NSolve[{SvA[zm, zs] == 0, tzmzs[zm, zs] == 0}, {zm, zs}]

NIntegrate::nlim: z = zm is not a valid limit of integration.
NIntegrate::nlim: z = zs is not a valid limit of integration.
NIntegrate::nlim: z = zs is not a valid limit of integration.
General::stop: Further output of NIntegrate::nlim will be suppressed during this calculation.
NIntegrate::ilim: Invalid integration variable or limit(s) in Reduce`ReduceVar[1].
NIntegrate::ilim: Invalid integration variable or limit(s) in Reduce`ReduceVar[1].
NIntegrate::ilim: Invalid integration variable or limit(s) in Reduce`ReduceVar[1].
General::stop: Further output of NIntegrate::ilim will be suppressed during this calculation.
NSolve[{-NIntegrate[SA[z, zs], {z, 1/10, zs}] + NIntegrate[Sv[z, zm], {z, 1/10, zm}] == 0, -10.203 - NIntegrate[tzs[z, zs], {z, 0, zs}] + NIntegrate[tzm[z, zm], {z, 0, 10, zm}, Method -> PrincipalValue] == 0}, {zm, zs}]
```

So problem occurs when solving those two equations in two unknowns. Another issue is that I don't know where to put the constraint `zh < zm < zm-critical` and `zs < zh`. If I use `NIntegrate`, definitely it is not an option there. If I use `Integrate` then I can put it there using `Assumptions` but I cannot use `Method -> PrincipalValue`.

Any suggestions or thoughts on how to go about this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably there is no solution in the range you are looking for. To show this we can visualize solution of two equations with using `ContourPlot[]` as follows

```
d = 3;
b = 0.1;
tb = 10.103;
zmcritical = 13.128;
zh = 10;
f[z_] := 1 - (z/zh)^(d + 1)
Sv[z_?NumericQ, zm_?NumericQ] := 
 zm^d/(z^d Sqrt[zm^(2 d) f[z] - z^(2 d) f[zm]])
SA[z_?NumericQ, zs_?NumericQ] := 
 zs^d/(z^d Sqrt[f[z] (zs^(2 d) - z^(2 d))])
SvA[zm_?NumericQ, zs_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[Sv[z, zm], {z, 10^-1, zm}] - 
  NIntegrate[SA[z, zs], {z, 10^-1, zs}]
tzm[z_?NumericQ, 
  zm_?NumericQ] := -1/(f[z] Sqrt[1 - (zm^(2 d) f[z])/(z^(2 d) f[zm])])
tzs[z_?NumericQ, zs_?NumericQ] := z^d/Sqrt[f[z] (zs^(2 d) - z^(2 d))]
tzmzs[zm_?NumericQ, zs_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[tzm[z, zm], {z, 0, zh, zm}, Method -> PrincipalValue] - 
  NIntegrate[tzs[z, zs], {z, 0, zs}] - b - tb

pic = {ContourPlot[{SvA[zm, zs] == 0}, {zm, 12.5, 13.1279}, {zs, 8, 
    9.99}, ContourStyle -> Blue], 
  ContourPlot[{tzmzs[zm, zs] == 0}, {zm, 12.5, 13.1279}, {zs, 8, 
    9.99}, ContourStyle -> Red]}

Show[pic]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Each point of the blue line is where each pair `(zm,zs)` satisfies $\eqref{1}$ right? So it means from that I can already conclude what `zm` will make $\eqref{1}$ equal to zero given the `zs` from the pair, although the red line just shows that the constraint of $\eqref{2}$ $\eqref{3}$ will not produce the same pair of `(zm,zs)` right?

Comment: Also, from the plot of `SvA[zm,zs]` (blue line), what does `SvA[12.8, 9] = 0.00319888` mean? `(12.8, 9)` is not on the blue line but `SvA[12.8, 9]` produces a value, albeit small.

Comment: @mathemania The blue line consist of solution of equation `SvA[zm, zs] == 0`, and red line consist of solution of equation `tzmzs[zm, zs] == 0`. The crossing of two lines consists of solution two equations { SvA[zm, zs] == 0, tzmzs[zm, zs] == 0`. Unfortunately there is no crossing points in the region you are looking for.

Comment: I see. However, suppose I can modify the constraints or study the system I am using so as to accommodate a solution of the two equations, how can I make my code work as in my post? NSolve produces an error.

Comment: @mathemania In numerical computation we also can use  `FindRoot[]`. First we can estimate solution with `ContourPlot` and then solve it with `FindRoot` , for example  `FindRoot[{SvA[zm, zs] == 0, tzmzs[zm, zs] + 7 == 0}, {{zm, 13.08}, {zs, 9.9}},  PrecisionGoal -> 6, AccuracyGoal -> 3]` we have out `{zm -> 13.0884, zs -> 9.93653}`